# Why the label is not filled in "for" with Thread

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use simple routine that when I passing in the **For** change label value.
I put a sleep one second, but nothing happens

Why this doesn't work?
I was debbuging and saw the value passing for the label, but not change in screen.

**CODE**

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNumber = 0;

for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++)
{
    randomNumber = rand.Next(1, 10);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    lblNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber);
}

lblNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber);
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: I want to know the reason these not working, Yes is windows forms

Comment: How would the main thread do the work to re-draw the window if it's asleep?

Answer (score 6):

> but not change in screen.

You're blocking the user interface thread.  The label will only update once when the method is completed, and the user interface can process messages properly.

If you want to see updates, you would need to move this "work" onto a background thread, and marshal the calls to set the text box back onto the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a Thread.Sleep on the UI Thread is not going to cause it to update the display (putting it to sleep just causes it to give up it's time on the processor for a period of aprox. 1 sec).

If you really wanted to trigger an update, you might consider invoking: `Application.DoEvents()` in place of the Thread.Sleep. That would cause the UI thread to process pending messages (which will include some repaint messages due to the change in the label's text) which will in turn re-paint the control.

But you should know that both methods are considered bad practice and are indicative of some problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the text of the label tells the program "the next time you update how this form looks, redrawn the label". But since you are putting the thread that is going to do the drawing to sleep, it is not redrawing the label until it wakes up.

Sleep is not what you want to do here; if you are calling Sleep on a UI thread then you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

If you're using C# 5 you can solve this problem by marking your method `async` and then using

```
await Task.Delay(whatever);
```

instead of `Thread.Sleep`. "await" means "go do something asynchronously, but don't go to sleep waiting for the result. Instead, return control to the caller. When the asynchronous operation is complete, a message will be sent to the UI thread that says to resume this method where you left off".

In order to use `await`, the method you are awaiting *in* has got to return `void` or `Task` or `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call

```
randomNumber = rand.Next(1, 10);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
lblNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber);
lblNumber.Refresh();
```

Answer (score -1):

This occurs because your UI update run in another thread. Unless you use a different thread, you will not see the label changes.
You can use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to accomplish this.

Comment: `Task.Run()` should really be used instead of `BackgroundWorker`. See this series of articles by Stephen Cleary for details: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html

Comment: @NewellClark this answer has almost 4 years old... It was perfectly valid then