# Refresh in silverlight seems textbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

There are something seems like command `txtBox.Text.Refesh()` for Windows Phone?

Comment: Note to those who read this question - It's a follow on from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441265/why-the-label-is-not-filled-in-for-with-thread.  One of the answers includes calling "refresh" on a control to get the screen to update.  What Ivo really needs to do is know how to pump messages in a silverlight application.  Likely the design is procedural instead of event driven so the issues are deeper than simply how to get messages processed.

Comment: You really really need to learn MVVM if you are working with XAML-based technologies. You're too far away from the right track. And no there's no such thing as `FrameworkElement.Refresh()`. Much less will you find a `Refresh()` method in the `Text` property, which is of type `string`.

Comment: As @HighCore said, if there was a Refresh method, it wouldn't on the Text property.  Properties are for reading and writing data to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Before I give my reply... As HighCore suggested in the comment - **you are probably doing it wrong** - you should probably change how you work to fit more with the framework. That said..

You can do this in many ways, but here are two fairly trivial ones.

1. Option 1: the fancy way.

Download and install the async CTP. This will allow you to use async/await semantics.

Do something like this:

```
async void Button_Click()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
textbox.Text = i.ToString();
await Task.Delay(1000);
}
}
```

1. Option 2: Good'ol way.

If you don't want to install the async CTP, refactor your code in the following manner:

```
void Button_Click()
{
  int i = 0;
  var t = new DispatcherTimer();
  t.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  t.Tick += (s, e) => { textbox.Text = i.ToString; i++; if (i == 20) t.Stop(); };
  t.Start();
}
```

Note that when this code is running, your app remains responsive which means that people may activate code you don't want them to.